# Connecting to Google Cloud SQL with MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql-workbench, google-cloud-sql

I can't seem to connect to Cloud SQL with Workbench. I keep getting this error.

```
Failed to Connect to MySQL at CLOUD-SQL-IPv4:3306 with user root

Access denied for use 'root'@'WHITE-LISTED-IP-ADDRESS' (using password: YES)
```

1. I have white listed my IP.
2. I have set an IP for the SQL instance.
3. I have checked the username and Password several times.

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have to create a new user in the `Google Cloud Console` with the `host name` set to `%(any host)`. You can't seem to connect using the root user.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to connect with the @root user but after you finish the setup you have to restart the sql server.

What is important to set up an SSL certificate if you connect to you production database, but if you only try it out you can allow unsecured connection. Another important thing is to add your IP to the Authorised Networks in the Connection tab.